# can't record cloud points

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,i am trying to record object model using Roboearth stack
firstly , i set up my enviroment kinect and marker
then, opened openni launch for the kinect
and enabled depth_registeration
after that i begin to
**rosrun re_object_recorder record_gui**

and the gui opened but can't recieved any cloud points !!

maker detected well and light is fine like in pictures below
i decreased distance of marker in gui but still no recieved any cloud point !!

any help ??

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

and rviz can't recieve any cloud point too !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48688/can%27t-record-cloud-points/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-11-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Saphrosit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2516/saphrosit/) on 2012-11-20**:
I don't know the visualization tool you are using, but did you try to simply zoom out? From the images you posted I see few spare points, maybe the cloud is too large to fit the screen.

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-21**:
No these spare points are boundry box points not cloud points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It admittedly takes a bit of experience to find a working setup.
Take a look at [these hints](http://www.ros.org/wiki/re_object_recorder?distro=fuerte#Common_Problems_and_Solutions).

Seeing your picture, I suggest to make sure that the marker pattern is completely planar. If all fails, you can adjust the 'marker_dist_threshold' parameter as described in the page linked above.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-21**:
@ddimarco thanks !,,,